# Enable Sleep Windows 10

Tags: windows, sleep, power, hibernate

I was trying to enable hibernate on my Windows 10 PC. (It was purchased as Win10, I did not update it from 7 or 8). I typed `powercfg -h on` in an elevated command prompt. When I shut down my computer and turned it on the next day, hibernate did not appear in my power menu, and sleep vanished as well. I tried `powercfg -h on` again, but neither sleep or hibernate showed up. My laptop appears to sleep when I close its lid. Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

I managed to get hibernate in my power menu, but sleep is not there. I went to `control panel`>`power options`>`change what closing the lid does`>`Show hibernate in power menu`. But I still want sleep to appear there again.

Comment: Did you use the control panel > Power Options to add hibernate to the power menu?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 how do I do this

Comment: Did you try.... **Windows Key + X**, click on **Control Panel**, from there select **Power Options**, and now look there through various settings such as perhaps **Change when he computer sleeps**?

Comment: Run a **`powercfg -a`** and see what sleep states are available on your PC at the OS level, and then go into BIOS and perhaps change accordingly from there if needed. Also ensure that it does not make a difference for options available from that window option when plugged in versus battery power only too (no dropdown for on **battery/plugged in** areas).

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Sleep was available until I ran `powercfg -h on`, so I don't think I need to really go as in depth as the bios. What is the equivalent to turn on sleep maybe?